# how to get the selected item from a combo-panel in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, combobox

I have an editable datagrid in easy ui with two combo boxes. As the second combo box should be loaded based on the first combo box selection, I have set the second combo box options using combo panel item.

Now I have to get the selected value from the combo panel using jquery.

Kindly help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Kindly share your code

Comment: Can you post the code for clarity

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#YourcomboboxId option:selected').val(); // It give selected value
```

Or

```
$('#YourcomboboxId option:selected').text(); // It give selected text
```